# bootstrap 3 typeahead.js : Where could i find a working example code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

[image]I am looking for a working example of typeahead. I want to use it but i don't find a snippet code which works with bootstrap 3. I want to do autocomplete as here http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ .If you have some link, thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? any feature or somthing to clarify your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Bootsrap it's hard because TYPEHEAD for exp.:

## FULL DOC

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <style>
            html {
              font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
              font-size: 18px;
              line-height: 1.2;
              color: #333;
            }
            .tt-dropdown-menu{
              text-align: left;
            }
            .typeahead,
            .tt-query,
            .tt-hint {
              padding: 8px 12px;
              font-size: 24px;
              outline: none;
            }
            .typeahead {
              background-color: #fff;
            }
            .tt-query {
              -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
                 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
                      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
            }
            .tt-hint {
              color: #999
            }
            .tt-dropdown-menu {
              width: 422px;
              margin-top: 12px;
              padding: 8px 0;
              background-color: #fff;
              border: 1px solid #ccc;
              border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
              -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
                 -moz-border-radius: 8px;
                      border-radius: 8px;
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
                 -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
                      box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            }
            .tt-suggestion {
              padding: 3px 20px;
              font-size: 18px;
              line-height: 24px;
            }
            .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
              color: #fff;
              background-color: #0097cf;
            }
            .tt-suggestion p {
              margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="countries"> <!-- This is a .countries in that examples.js -->
                <div class="demo">
                    <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" placeholder="Countries" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" > <!-- This is a typehead class in that js-->
                    <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" disabled="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="visibility: hidden; ">
                    <pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 24px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; text-transform: none;">
                    </pre>
                    <span class="tt-dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;">
                        <div class="tt-dataset-countries"></div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="./typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
            <script src="./examples.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in examples.js is:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var numbers;
var countries = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 10,
  prefetch: {
    url: './countries.json',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(country) { return { name: country }; });
    }
  }
});

countries.initialize();

$('.countries .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'countries',
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: countries.ttAdapter()
});

});
```

## Local way

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var numbers;
    var countries = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 10,
        local: [
            { name: 'Andorra' },
            { name: 'United Arab Emirates' },
            { name: 'Afghanistan'},
            { name: 'Antigua and Barbuda'},
            { name: 'Anguilla'},
        ]
    });

countries.initialize();

$('.countries .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: countries.ttAdapter()
});

});
```

Comment: VeeeneX thanks for your response. I've tried it but auto complete does not work  see http://pastebin.com/S6NRf3hJ

Comment: Yeah, Best way how to fix it is look at Console for exp. in Chrome F12  and there is: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery bootstrap.min.js:6
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/countries.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: VeeeneX thanks again for your help. I am trying the FULL DOC but it's does not work. I am getting a stange error on chrome debug console.  CAUTION:Provisional headers are shown. I add the screen shot on the question

Comment: Well friend the problem is on your side try to disable extensions in Chrome or (the better way) as i've written to asnwer

Comment: VeeeneX as you've suggested it's work with local data but no with the data from the server ( using prefetch).

Comment: Thanks VeeeneX, i finally understand what's happening. Correct me if i am wrong. When we use typeahead prefetch. On page loading a XMLHttpRequest is send to get data and store them in local storage.And data will be used in autocomplete. But as we know XMLHttpRequest  is subject to the same-origin policy [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). To send a XMLHttpRequest the web page must be on the same server than the server app which respon to the request.So i've changed the prefetch url to a local path. It's work like a charm.

Comment: Yeah friend, XMLHttpRequest ;)

Comment: In this example, typing "Emi" will find United Arab Emirates, but typing "mi" won't. It seems that it only searches at the start of a word. Is there a possible modification that will search within words too?

Comment: @M.M Yes, you can configure length of string via [minLength](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadoptions-datasets)