# Using input as the trigger for bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a search area and have decided to use the dropdown feature of bootstrap's framework.

What I aim to achieve is this:

1. A user types something, then another function parses the results.
2. I call a function or something that triggers that dropdown events.

If I just trigger the class responsible for the dropdown menu visibility, the rest of the functionality doesn't work (for instance, the keyboard navigation on the dropdown list items).

On the other hand, if I follow the documentation, and add: data-toggle="dropdown" to the input element
Then each click / focus on the input shows the dropdown, which is not what I want, I want to trigger it on my own.

Here's the HTML (couldn't create a working fiddle):

```
<div id="search-field" class="custom-dropdown">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="global-search-input" data-toggle="dropdown" maxlength="255" name="top-search" placeholder="Global Search" tabindex="1" />
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="global-search-input">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Anything ? I could use some help :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like Typehead.js, that display dropdown for actions check the
[Typehead example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081780/bootstrap-3-typeahead-js-where-could-i-find-a-working-example-code/22082597)